# CSS drop down menu expands entire nav bar when drop down menu appears

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a pure css drop down menu. Everything works fine except for when I hover to drop the menu down, the entire nav bar also gets expanded and I don't want it to do that. Here is my code:

```
.nav-bar { 
  list-style:none; 
}

#right {
  padding-right: 100px;
}

#right li { 
  display: inline; 
  float: right;
  padding: 3% 0 0.5% 0;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

#right li img {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #right {
    display: none;
  }
}

#nav-refer {
  padding: 5% 15% 5% 15%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #FFC52D;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue Bold';
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #nav-refer {
    display: none;
  }
}

#left {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

#left li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -30px;
 }

 #left li img {
   padding: 0 0 0 15px;
 }

 .drop_menu {
    background: white;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
   /*height: 30px;*/
  }

.drop_menu li { 
   float:left; 
}

        .drop_menu li a {
            padding:9px 20px;
            display:block;
            color: black;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-family: 'Bebas Neue Regular';
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        .drop_menu li a img {
            width: 60%; 
            height: auto;
            padding: 0px;
        }

            /* Submenu */
        .drop_menu ul {
            position: absolute;
            left:-9999px;
            top:-9999px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .drop_menu:hover {
            display:block;
            height: 110px;

        }

        .drop_menu li:hover { 
            position:relative; 
            height: 30px;
        }

        .drop_menu li:hover ul {
            left:70px;
            top:50px;
            background: white;
            padding:0px;
        }

        .drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
            padding:10px;
            display:block;
            width:168px;
            text-indent:15px;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { 
            background: #E6E6E6; 
            padding: 5px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 1000px) {
            #left {
                display: none;
            }
        }

    <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul id="left">
             <ul class="drop_menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src={{asset('images/hamburger2.png')}}></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#refer">REFER-A-FRIEND</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <li><img src={{asset('images/shine2_logo.png')}}></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="right">
            <li><a href="#refer" id="nav-refer">REFER FRIENDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ShineText" target="_blank"><img src={{asset('images/twitter_Icon.png')}}></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/ShineText" target="_blank"><img src={{asset('images/instagram_Icon.png')}}></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Shine-Text" target="_blank"><img src={{asset('images/facebook_Icon.png')}}></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share your demo link?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the navbar code so that we can see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Ive updated your CSS, you had some styles in the wrong place and you were also expanding the height of the menu when you hovered on the first `<li>`.

I also updated the position of the `.drop_menu li:hover ul {` to be 100% from the top of the parent `<li>`.

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.drop_menu {
  background: white;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  background: green;
}

.drop_menu > li { 
  float:left;  
  position:relative; 
}

.drop_menu li a {
  padding:9px 20px;
  display:block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue Regular';
  font-size: 22px;
}

.drop_menu li a img {
  width: 60%; 
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  top:-9999px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.drop_menu:hover {
  display:block;
  /* height: 110px; */
}


.drop_menu li:hover ul {
  left:70px;
  top: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
  width:168px;
  text-indent:15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { 
  background: #E6E6E6; 
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="drop_menu clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">hamburger</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#refer">REFER-A-FRIEND</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this still didn't work for me. When I hover, the more I dropped down the menu list, it would disappear by the third `li`

Comment: you can see from my example above it does work with the code that you've supplied. You must have some other CSS in your site that is effecting the navigation! @chloealee

Comment: Yes, I think you're right and thank you so much for taking so much time to help, Aaron! I really appreciate it :) My code is wrapped by two other divs - I will update my code now! Any ideas what might be causing it now?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind marking my answer as correct then please.

Comment: are you able to help with the updated code? Then I will mark as correct so it's no misleading!